DC-DC converter design simulation tools and Webench design tools to identify the best-suited IC and schematic
I did a research about what are the simulation tools and webench tools for major companies like AD and TI to find a effective tools for my design purpose:
For example for Analog Devices, there is the following tool for webench, then we can select our desire input and output voltage, then it gives suggestions for the circuits and the chip:
https://analog.transim.com/Loader/New.aspx?tool=pwm2&page=Schematic

For TI:
https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator

My issue is that my input voltage is 4-5 V and I need a dual variable output from +/-6 V to +/-80 V (25 mA), but for example TI webench does not accept dual output and even negative output, and regarding Analog Devices, it accepts both dual and negative output, but it does not suggest me anything, so I wonder what software or webench I can use for my design? to be able to find the correct chip and circuit for this design?
Regards,

Have you considered separate converter for positive and negative supply?

@winny not I did not, I saw this reference design from TI: https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-010057 and they could build it with a single IC, but the simulation of the design has several issue, so I decided to look for alternatives. Do you suggest that I make it separate?

Depends on your load regulation requirements. Unbalanced loads would be much easier to regulate on two separate converters. If your requirements for that is low, it could be cheaper to build a single dual output one.

@winny my load is an ultrasound MEMS device, it has 1nF capacitator inside and there are128 channels. Then we want to generate a pulse (positive and negative amplitude) to excite the MEMS device, so it seems that the load is symmetric.

These tools, are nothing more than that: tools. They can offer suggestions (sometimes even complete designs!), but there will never be a substitute for using your noggin'.
Particularly for the wide voltage range, you'll have a hard time solving that with stock IC-based solutions.  A little bit of customization will go a long way.
In respect of that, consider two options:

Custom transformer
Dual windings

Likely a major pitfall of the stock solutions these tools are programmed for, is few or no transformer options.  There aren't many options in this range anyway, but I expect they are programmed with only a sampling of all commercial parts -- not to mention, alternative configurations thereof.
Offhand, I would guess there are PoE and telecom (36-72V) transformers that would be viable here.  Flyback topology.
If you need tracking outputs, a dual-winding transformer, or combo SEPIC-Ćuk converter (or a combination of both, as the case may be), can save a lot of work.
If you need precise tracking, likely you'll want to use a post-regulator or LDO, probably on the negative side via op-amp + level shift + PNP follower, and by adding a few volts overhead on the negative side to account for the drop (the positive output can be controlled by SMPS feedback as normal).
Or if nothing else, you could do worse than a ±100V supply, and use a conventional linear tracking regulator design, upscaled for the voltage as appropriate.  The 25mA requirement is only ~5W total, easily accessible from a USB charger for example, and not needing much heatsinking.  You don't mention whether efficiency is a priority, so it's worth mentioning the option in case.
